# Outputting 2 lists of data, but keeping them organised IN VB

Tags: vb.net, forms, list, organization

This will hopefully be my last question for a while and with what i have gained from yourselves will help me really get on with this project!
So... i currently have variosu combo boxes and text boxes being put into a list of strings on FORM2, all blanks ignored then output into list boxes on FORM3. this is my final piece..
combobox 1 will be populated with say "Premium", then textbox 1 will have 4 values "400,500,600,700"
then combo box2 with "Cover" and textbox2 "TPO,TPFT,COMP"

i want it to look as follows any ---- are just for spacing out as it appears to ignore the spacebar

**Listbox1** --- | --- **ListBox2**
Premium ------------ 400
-------------------------500
-------------------------600
-------------------------700
Cover-----------------TPO
-------------------------TPFT

etc etc.
what i am getting is

**Listbox1** --- | --- **ListBox2**
Premium ------------ 400
Cover-----------------500
-------------------------600
-------------------------700
-------------------------TPO
-------------------------TPFT

there is no relation between the fields and i haven't a clue how to best describe or look-up how to do this, make it output combo box one, then textbox1 split into lines into a second box. then under these the next combo box etc. so i guess combobox + ((Textbox 1 lines -1 value) as blank lines)
if i could put pictures up this would be so much easier! darnnn youu reputation!!!!

At last i can have pictures!!!!!
[image]
As you can hopefully see, form 1 is irrelevant at the momemnt (will have no impact on the GUI for form2/3)
but you pick various fields in form 2 and they ar mapped to form3
ATM some of the data is being mapped in a strange order. and there is no formatting between list 1 and 2

Find below a early concept of Form2 and Form3[image: Form2 and Form3 Early Concept]

This is what i am trying to do, the data is lay out in a readable format (and behind the scenes ran through various DROOLS that will morph the data and print the results of this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong control for the job.  You need a control that can display multiple columns of data for each item in a list.  The `ListBox` control is not well-suited for that, since it is designed for just showing a single column.

Assuming this is a WinForm project, and not WPF, I would recommend using either a `DataGridView` control, or a `ListView` control.  Either of those controls can show multiple columns, although, the `ListView` control only shows multiple columns with its `View` property is set to `Details`.  Since I'm partial to the `ListView` control, myself, I'll give you an example using that one :)

First, add a `ListView` control to your form.  Then, set the `View` property of the control, in the designer, to `Details`.  Then click the button to edit the `Columns` property of the control.  Add two columns.  Then, use code like this to populate the list:

```
Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add("Premium")
item.SubItems.Add("400")
item = ListView1.Items.Add("")
item.SubItems.Add("500")
item = ListView1.Items.Add("")
item.SubItems.Add("600")
item = ListView1.Items.Add("")
item.SubItems.Add("700")
item = ListView1.Items.Add("Cover")
item.SubItems.Add("TPO")
item = ListView1.Items.Add("")
item.SubItems.Add("TPFT")
```

If, as seems to be the case, the text for the first column is stored in a combo box, then the text for the second column are stored in a comma-delimited text box, then you could do something like this:

```
For Each cbo As ComboBox In MyComboBoxes
    Dim first As Boolean = True
    For Each value As String In GetTextBoxForComboBox(cbo).Text.Split(",")
        Dim item As ListViewItem = Nothing
        If first Then
            item = ListView1.Items.Add(cbo.Text)
        Else
            item = ListView1.Items.Add("")
        End If
        item.SubItems.Add(value)
        first = False
    Next
Next
```

Of course, rather than having a method like `GetTextBoxForComboBox`, it would be better to have have a class that stores the pairing of controls, like this:

```
Private Class ControlPair
    Public Property Cbo As ComboBox
    Public Property Txt As TextBox
End Class
```

Then, you could just loop through them like this:

```
For Each pair As ControlPair In MyPairs
    ' ...
    For Each value As String In pair.Txt.Text.Split(",")
        ' ...
        ListView1.Items.Add(pair.Cbo.Text)
        ' ...
    Next
Next
```

`For Each` is a convenient syntax for iterating through all of the items in an `IEnumerable` object (basically any list such as an `Array` or a `List(Of T)`).  So, in this case, the `MyPairs` would need to be a list of `ControlPair` objects, for instance:

```
Dim MyPairs As New List(Of ControlPair)()
Dim pair1 As New ControlPair()
pair1.Cbo = ComboBox1
pair1.Txt = TextBox1
MyPairs.Add(pair1)
Dim pair2 As New ControlPair()
pair2.Cbo = ComboBox2
pair2.Txt = TextBox2
MyPairs.Add(pair2)
```

Or, if you don't want to make your own class, you could just use `Tuple(Of ComboBox, TextBox)`.

Actually, after seeing your screenshots, it looks like the `TreeView` control may actually be more appropriate.  You could have each combo box value show as a root-level node, and then inside each root-level node would be a child-node for each of the delimited values in the text box, like this:

- Premium

  - 400
  - 500
  - 600
  - 700
- Cover

  - TPO
  - TPFT

Comment: It has appently deleted my reply to this, this makes sense i can see hwo it would work, but obviously they are not hard coded values i would be inputting, they are data manually picked out/typed in on form 2 in combo box's and text boxs.
Could i use something along what we have done in the past? seperate as string collections and use combobox1 as Items.add() then textbox 1's string split (",") as subitems, then combo 2.... etc?  p.s i have attached an early concept above that may show it a little clearer

Comment: Absolutely.  I just showed the hard-coded values as an example.  You can just as easily write a for loop that loads the items from a list or an array.

Comment: Urrrggg i suck at VB tried a couple of things just to take what you have show me (works perfectly) and make it put out something from the array as Items.Add()
Cant get anything to work, i really need to sit down for a few days and learn the basics of VB really. rather than keep asking questions endlessly :P Lets say i make an array/list of combo box's and a separate list of Text box's how would i bring these into the above listview, also how would i make it know where to put the combo box answers as each one could have 1 or 5 values, would it be easier to store each box seperatly?

Comment: Well you have just blown my mind apart, take me a while to get my head around all of that, i imagine you will hear from me in a day or two! :P Thanks Steven

Comment: For Each pair As ControlPair In MyPairs********** Think i understand all of this, but can you explain what eahc thign above is. my understands is "pair" is you declaring a "variable" then ControlPair refers to the private class created, no idea what "MyPairs" is. in otherwords i have no idea what to change these values to for my own work :P

Comment: You are correct.  `pairs` is the local iterator variable for the loop and `ControlPair` is the class (the type of the iterator variable).  I will update my answer to describe what `MyPairs` is.

Answer (score 0):

Never rely on white space or blank lines for formatting. Write proper markup.

```
<form>
<label>Premium</label>
<select name="premium">
    <option>400</option>
    <option>500</option>
    <option>600</option>
    <option>700</option>
</select><br><br>
<label>Cover</label>
<select name="cover">
    <option>TPO</option>
    <option>TPFT</option>
    <option>COMP</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: well the thing is anythign can be put into the text box's its kinda hard to explain without pictures  
Combo box 1 has around 100 values to pick, then textbox one can have any number of values put into it on form2 that will be output into a form/list on form3 (and eventaully have these values ran through a testharness and the output values output into a third list on form3. but for now im just trying to get the static information carried across and displayed correctly.

Comment: Updated with pictures! my rep jumped up :)

Comment: Apologies. I answered as thought is was a HTML question. I see now that you did tag the question as vb.net forms but it would have been clearer if you'd defined context in the question.

Comment: Ahhh sorry about that, Coffee hadn't quite kicked in when i was typing this up!