# Looping through each item in a ListBox control with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ldap

I wrote the below program to look up an LDAP user and return back a property.  The way I need it to work is as follows: first I will load a list of user ID's into `ListBox1`, then when I click a button a property (such as DisplayName) will be appended to `ListBox2`.  Right now I have to click on an item in `ListBox1` and then click the button and it works, but I want it to loop through every ID in `ListBox1` and write the properties for all of them to `ListBox2` without me having to click on each user ID.  How can I put the below in a for each loop?

```
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com/DC=test,DC=com")
Dim LdapFilter As String = "(sAMAccountName=" & ListBox1.Text & ")"
Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(de, LdapFilter)
Dim result As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne()
ListBox2.Items.Add(result.Properties("displayName")(0).ToString())
```

**Update**

I tried to use a `ListView` to display two columns, as suggested.  It's not working, however.  It just adds the `ListView` columns:

```
Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add("Username")
Dim item1 As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add("Title")
For Each i As String In ListBox1.Items
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com/DC=test,DC=com")
    Dim LdapFilter As String = "(sAMAccountName=" & i & ")"
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(de, LdapFilter)
    Dim result As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne()
    item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0).ToString())
    item1.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("title")(0).ToString())
    Dim ADEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(result.Path)
    If result.Properties("displayName") Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using the `ListBox1.Text` property.  It's rather confusing.  In this case, you want to loop through all of the strings in the `ListBox1.Items` list (presuming they are actually strings).  For instance:

```
For Each i As String in ListBox1.Items
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com/DC=test,DC=com")
    Dim LdapFilter As String = "(sAMAccountName=" & i & ")"
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(de, LdapFilter)
    Dim result As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne()
    ListBox2.Items.Add(result.Properties("displayName")(0).ToString())
Next
```

Or, if `ListBox1` doesn't actually contain strings, you could loop through them as `Object` and call the `ToString` method on each one, like this:

```
For Each i As Object in ListBox1.Items
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com/DC=test,DC=com")
    Dim LdapFilter As String = "(sAMAccountName=" & i.ToString() & ")"
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(de, LdapFilter)
    Dim result As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne()
    ListBox2.Items.Add(result.Properties("displayName")(0).ToString())
Next
```

As I mentioned in the comments below, rather than using two separate `ListBox` controls, it would be preferable to use a `ListView` control with two columns.  For instance, if you had a `ListView1` control with three columns (entitled "ID", "Username", and "Title"), then you could add the items like this:

```
Dim userIds As IEnumerable(Of String) = getAllLdapUserIds()  ' Get the list of ID's using whatever means you are currently using
For Each i As String In userIds
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com/DC=test,DC=com")
    Dim LdapFilter As String = "(sAMAccountName=" & i & ")"
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(de, LdapFilter)
    Dim result As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne()
    Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(i)
    item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0).ToString())
    item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("title")(0).ToString())
Next
```

Comment: you are the man!!! first option worked because i will have strings in there.  Could you tell me how to make 2 column headers and put the items returned under there?  Basically what i want is this:  The usernames would be pulled from the first listbox

Username    Email
johndoe    johndoe@test.com

Comment: For two columns, I would recommend using a `ListView` control with the `View` property set to `Details`.  However, the `DataGridView` control is another popular alternative.

Comment: Here's [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920322/outputting-2-lists-of-data-but-keeping-them-organised-in-vb/15926375#15926375) where I show how to display two columns of data in a `ListView` control.  That should give you a good idea of how it works.

Comment: Thank you!
Where is getAllLdapUserIds() defined?  Its currently not set to anything?

Comment: It's an imaginary function which returns a list of strings (one per user id).  You didn't show the code that loaded `ListBox1`, so I just pretended that you had such a function.  If you don't, you should :)

Comment: LOL, i started to think that.  Well i am going to load them by textfile, but for now i manaully entered 5 userids in a ListBox1.  How could i call whats manually in there right now?  Ill worry about loading the textfile later

Comment: Just hard-code them in, for instance: `Dim userIds As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"1", "2", "3"}`

Comment: ill have to tinker with this, its not placing each result under the columns i made, it just places the results in one long line

Comment: And you're calling `ListView1.Items.Add(i)` each time, like I am in my example?  Surely you must not be.  Or at least you aren't setting the `item` variable equal to the result of the `Add` function each time.

Comment: i got it, i had the wrong default view.  thanks so much for your help!!!  view was set to largeicon versus details.  Once i switched it worked fine!